# A word for conflicting emotions

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for conflicting emotions all felt at once such as loneliness, sadness, happiness, being content but also feeling as if something isn't right?

Comment: Is it enough to call that “*a jumble of emotions*”?

Comment: Will "torn" work here?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it always like that? I feel you, like, maybe, I don't know. Wait. What? Confusion. Dissonance. Discord. What you describe are mostly feelings, not "emotions." Emotions are more basic, physical, measurable (like via a lie detector test) - survival instinct stuff. Then come the feelings - emotion mixed with thought, bias, sense, perception. Before you know it, you don't know it. How do you feel about that?

Comment: I feel that is borderline incoherent.  Are emotions measurable?  Certainly not by lie detectors, which measure pulse, respiration rate, and skin impedance.  Do you have any source for your claim that feelings are "emotion mixed with thought"?

Comment: I agree my post is

Comment: I agree my post is "borderline incoherent," a poor attempt at exemplifying the "conflicting emotions" in a great question by @lily. However, emotions are physical and manifest partly in the measurements you describe. Debbie Hamilton explains it well on (www.thebestbrainpossible.com/whats-the-difference-between-feelings-and-emotions), referencing neuroscientist Antonio D’Amasio (bigthink.com/experts/antoniodamasio): "Feelings are mental experiences of body states, which arise as the brain interprets emotions, themselves physical states arising from the body’s responses to external stimuli."